# Triggering LogicApp from datafactory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, runtime-environment

i have a data factory with selfhosted runtime environment of windows 2016 VMScaleSet.

I have created logic app with access control configured to access from vmss. i created http trigger in logic app.

when i try to invoke http trigger from datafactory web activity, i am getting following error

"errorCode": "2011",
    "message": "Could not load file or assembly 'CodeGenerator, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "SendMail",
    "details": []
}

i am not sure, what is this assembly and where is this assembly needs to be installed and registered.

please help me to resolve this issue.

thanks!!

Comment: Have you been able to invoke the Logic App using another method like Postman?

Comment: if i use AutoresolveIntegrationRuntime , flow is getting executed without any issue. when i select selfhosted runtime environment it fails. do we need to install any components in IR machine. its VMSS, its not having any tools installed in it.

Comment: My apologies, I don't have any experience with self-hosted runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled the Selfhosted Integrated runtime and installed new version of SHIR and .net framework latest version ie (.netframework 8).

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39717
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net48-web-installer

it resolved this issue. i am able to trigger logic app from my datafactory pipeline